# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 by Grouping

Tags: mysql

Can anybody help me with this script what am i doing wrong.....

```
    insert ignore into `sales`.`salesm`

    SELECT
    `sales_imp`.`mktcd`,
    sum(`sales_imp`.`sales_qty_dtl`),
    '0',
    sum(`sales_imp`.`sales_value_dtl`),
    '0',
    `sales_imp`.`yyyymm`,
    `nk_mktcd_itemcd_container_id`,
    `nk_mktcd_itemcd`,
    concat(`nk_mktcd_itemcd`,`sales_imp`.`yyyymm`),
    `agentcd`,
    `nk_mktcd_agentcd`,
    concat(`sales_imp`.`mktcd`,`sales_imp`.`agentcd`,`sales_imp`.`buyer_id_dtl`),
    concat(`sales_imp`.`mktcd`,`sales_imp`.`agentcd`,`sales_imp`.`producer_id_dtl`),
    concat(`sales_imp`.`mktcd`,`sales_imp`.`agentcd`,`sales_imp`.`salesman_id_dtl`),
    `nk_clssiz`

FROM `sales`.`sales_imp`
group by

`sales_imp`.`mktcd`,
`sales_imp`.`classid`,
`sales_imp`.`sizeid`,
`sales_imp`.`yyyymm`,
`nk_mktcd_itemcd_container_id`,
`nk_mktcd_itemcd`,
`buyer_id_dtl`,
`sales_imp`.`producer_id_dtl`,
`sales_imp`.`salesman_id_dtl`,
`agentcd`,
`nk_mktcd_agentcd`,
`nk_mktcd_agentcd_buyer_id`,
`nk_mktcd_agentcd_producer_id`,
`nk_mktcd_agentcd_sman_id`,
`nk_clssiz`;
```

Answer (score 0):

The number of columns in your target table seems to be different from the number of columns you are inserting values for. Try to name the columns you want the data to be inserted into :

```
    INSERT IGNORE INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)... Your SELECT QUERY
```

Comment: Thank you but could you maybe please guide me as what columns different as i am fairly new to this

Comment: When the number of columns you are trying to insert is different from the number of columns in your table, you will have to tell MySQL which value goes into which column. Use the following command to identify the columns you want the data to be inserted into: `show columns from sales.salesm` or just use `select * from sales.salesm limit 1`. If your columns have the same names as you are using in your select statement, the query would look like this:
`INSERT IGNORE INTO sales.salesm (mktcd, sales_qty_dtl, sales_value_dtl, yyyymm, ...) SELECT ...
GROUP BY ...`

Comment: Thank you so much i will give it a try and comment back asap